# How to keep track of winner in Connect Four Java game

Tags: java, arrays, console, drawing, java.util.scanner

This is a class that creates the game connect four in console and drawing panel, and I am having trouble in the `connectedFour` method where it determines if someone has gotten 4 discs in a row. The problem is, is that I am not sure how to set up my for loops to check through the array for four discs in a row
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ConnectFour{

   public static void main(String[] args){
      //board
      DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(550,550);
      int rowAvailable;
      Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
      g.drawLine(0,0,0,500);
      g.drawLine(0,0,500,0);
      g.drawLine(500,0,500,427);
      g.drawLine(0,427,500,427);
      for(int i = 0; i< 6; i++){
         for(int j= 0; j<= 6; j++){
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            g.fillRect(j*71,i*71,71,71);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(j*71,i*71,71,71); 

         }
      }

      //setBlankArray
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      char[][] board = new char[6][7];
      for(int j = 0;j <= 6; j++){
         for(int i= 0; i < 6; i++){
            board[i][j] = ' ';
         }
      }
      boolean isBlack = true;
      boolean isRed = false;
      int column = 0;
      boolean playersTurn = true;
      boolean rightNum = false;

      //oneTurn
      while(getWinner(board, playersTurn)){
      //while(playersTurn == true){
         rightNum = false;
         if(isBlack == true){
            // displayCurrentPlayer
            System.out.println("Black's Turn");
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Red Disc's Turn",200, 450);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString("Black Disc's Turn",200, 450);
         }
         else{
            // displayCurrentPlayer
            System.out.println("Red's Turn");
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawString("Black Disc's Turn",200, 450);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Red Disc's Turn",200, 450);
         }
         System.out.print("Choose a column to place your disk (1-7): ");
         while(rightNum == false){
            column = (console.nextInt()) -1;
            if(column >= 0 && column < 7 && board[0][column] == ' '){
               rightNum = true;
            }
            else{
               System.out.print("Try again: ");
            }
         }

         drawBoard(column, board, isBlack, isRed, board, g);
         isBlack = !isBlack;
      }
      if(isBlack == false){System.out.println("Congratulations Black Player");}
      else{System.out.println("Congratulations Red Player");}
      // use the while loop to say try again if the column is filled.
   }

   public static void drawBoard(int column, char[][] board, boolean isBlack, boolean isRed, char[][] availability,Graphics g){

      char player = ' ';
      if(isBlack == true){
         g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         player = 'b';
      }
      else{
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         player = 'r';
      }
      int x = 0;
      int row = 5;
      while(board[row-x][column] != ' '){
         x++;
      }
      row = row-x;
      g.fillOval((column * 71),(row * 71), 71,71);
      board[row][column] = player;
   }

   public static boolean getWinner(char[][] board, boolean playersTurn){
      int verticalCount = 0;
      boolean isVertical = false;
      for(int i = 6; i >= 0; i--){
         verticalCount = 0;         
         for(int j = 5; j > 0; j--){
            if(board[j][i] == board[j-1][i] && board[j][i] != ' '){
               verticalCount++;
            }
            if(verticalCount == 4){
               isVertical = true;
            }
         }
      }

      int horizontalCount = 0;
      boolean isHorizontal = false;
      for(int i =1; i <= 5; i++){
         for(int j =1; j<6; j++){
            if(board[j][i] == board[j][i+1] && board[j][i] != ' '){
               horizontalCount++;
            } 
            if(horizontalCount == 3){
               isHorizontal = true;
            }
         }
      }

      int diagonalCount = 0;
      boolean isDiagonal = false; 
     // for(int i = 0; i<=6; i++){
      //   for(int j =0; j<6; j++){
       //     if(board[i][j-1] == board[i][j]){
       //        diagonalCount++;
         //   } 
        // }
     // }

      if(isVertical || isHorizontal || isDiagonal){
         playersTurn = false;
      }
      else{
         playersTurn = true;}
      return playersTurn;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think it is not clear what your problem is. Can you descripe it?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by checking if the game-winning condition is met after a disc has been placed. This way you aren't iterating over the entire board after each move.

Regardless, try this:

replace

```
while (gameWon == false ){
```

with

```
while (!connectedFour(board, playersTurn)) {
```

I don't think this will completely fix your problems as it looks like there are a handful of other things wrong with the code you've posted.